# information about the number of polygons of a particular selected object

Tags: modeling, python, texturing

- Is there a way to get statistical information in Blender for
  an individual object, not all objects in the scene, how to view
  statistics of a separate selected grid, each time switch to the mode
  editing, even with the TAB hotkey, is very inconvenient
  ...
- It is also not clear why the transition to the local view with the
  key - /  also does not help to see the statistics of a separate
  object, only the editing mode how so?